# How to use zip() function as part of a subplot?

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop, matplotlib

**i have given a fairly sub plot function:**

```
def func_plot_test(Name, fileoutput):
    
    fig,axs = plt.subplots(5,1, sharex=True, figsize=(16,24))
    
    #index of axs; dataframe; column name; label
    axs[0].plot(df_var0_20[Name],color = plotcolors[0],label = "A",linewidth=3)
    axs[0].plot(df_var11_20[Name],color = plotcolors[1],label = "B",linewidth=3)
    axs[0].plot(df_var21_20[Name],'--',color = plotcolors[1],label = "C",linewidth=3)
    axs[0].plot(df_var12_20[Name],color = plotcolors[2],label = "D",linewidth=3)
    axs[0].plot(df_var22_20[Name],'--',color = plotcolors[2],label = "E",linewidth=3)
    axs[0].plot(df_var13_20[Name],color = plotcolors[3],label = "F",linewidth=3)
    axs[0].plot(df_var23_20[Name],'--',color = plotcolors[3],label = "G",linewidth=3)
    axs[0].plot(df_var14_20[Name],color = plotcolors[4],label = "H",linewidth=3)
    axs[0].plot(df_var24_20[Name],'--',color = plotcolors[4],label = "I",linewidth=3)
    
    axs[1].plot(df_var0_50[Name],color = plotcolors[0],label = "A",linewidth=3)
    axs[1].plot(df_var11_50[Name],color = plotcolors[1],label = "B",linewidth=3)
    axs[1].plot(df_var21_50[Name],'--',color = plotcolors[1],label = "C",linewidth=3)
    axs[1].plot(df_var12_50[Name],color = plotcolors[2],label = "D",linewidth=3)
    axs[1].plot(df_var22_50[Name],'--',color = plotcolors[2],label = "E",linewidth=3)
    axs[1].plot(df_var13_50[Name],color = plotcolors[3],label = "F",linewidth=3)
    axs[1].plot(df_var23_50[Name],'--',color = plotcolors[3],label = "G",linewidth=3)
    axs[1].plot(df_var14_50[Name],color = plotcolors[4],label = "H",linewidth=3)
    axs[1].plot(df_var24_50[Name],'--',color = plotcolors[4],label = "I",linewidth=3)
    
    axs[2].plot(df_var0_80[Name],color = plotcolors[0],label = "A",linewidth=3)
    axs[2].plot(df_var11_80[Name],color = plotcolors[1],label = "B",linewidth=3)
    axs[2].plot(df_var21_80[Name],'--',color = plotcolors[1],label = "C",linewidth=3)
    axs[2].plot(df_var12_80[Name],color = plotcolors[2],label = "D",linewidth=3)
    axs[2].plot(df_var22_80[Name],'--',color = plotcolors[2],label = "E",linewidth=3)
    axs[2].plot(df_var13_80[Name],color = plotcolors[3],label = "F",linewidth=3)
    axs[2].plot(df_var23_80[Name],'--',color = plotcolors[3],label = "G",linewidth=3)
    axs[2].plot(df_var14_80[Name],color = plotcolors[4],label = "H",linewidth=3)
    axs[2].plot(df_var24_80[Name],'--',color = plotcolors[4],label = "I",linewidth=3)
    
    axs[3].plot(df_var0_96[Name],color = plotcolors[0],label = "A",linewidth=3)
    axs[3].plot(df_var11_96[Name],color = plotcolors[1],label = "B",linewidth=3)
    axs[3].plot(df_var21_96[Name],'--',color = plotcolors[1],label = "C",linewidth=3)
    axs[3].plot(df_var12_96[Name],color = plotcolors[2],label = "D",linewidth=3)
    axs[3].plot(df_var22_96[Name],'--',color = plotcolors[2],label = "E",linewidth=3)
    axs[3].plot(df_var13_96[Name],color = plotcolors[3],label = "F",linewidth=3)
    axs[3].plot(df_var23_96[Name],'--',color = plotcolors[3],label = "G",linewidth=3)
    axs[3].plot(df_var14_96[Name],color = plotcolors[4],label = "H",linewidth=3)
    axs[3].plot(df_var24_96[Name],'--',color = plotcolors[4],label = "I",linewidth=3)
    
    axs[4].plot(df_var0_98[Name],color = plotcolors[0],label = "A",linewidth=3)
    axs[4].plot(df_var11_98[Name],color = plotcolors[1],label = "B",linewidth=3)
    axs[4].plot(df_var21_98[Name],'--',color = plotcolors[1],label = "C",linewidth=3)
    axs[4].plot(df_var12_98[Name],color = plotcolors[2],label = "D",linewidth=3)
    axs[4].plot(df_var22_98[Name],'--',color = plotcolors[2],label = "E",linewidth=3)
    axs[4].plot(df_var13_98[Name],color = plotcolors[3],label = "F",linewidth=3)
    axs[4].plot(df_var23_98[Name],'--',color = plotcolors[3],label = "G",linewidth=3)
    axs[4].plot(df_var14_98[Name],color = plotcolors[4],label = "H",linewidth=3)
    axs[4].plot(df_var24_98[Name],'--',color = plotcolors[4],label = "I",linewidth=3)
       

    plt.legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.15),
          fancybox=True, shadow=True, ncol=10,fontsize=14)
    
    fig.savefig(str(fileoutput)+ '.jpg',bbox_inches='tight',quality=95,dpi=300)
```

I'd like to make use of zip() in a way that i reduce each "block" to a oneliner and provide the necessary arguments or variables per line via the zip() function and call them in a for loop:

```
def func_plot_test1(Name,fileoutput,linewidth=3):
    
    fig,axs = plt.subplots(5,1, sharex=True, figsize=(16,24))
    
    #index of axs; dataframe; column name; label
    
    names_plot01 = ["df_var0_20","df_var11_20","df_var21_20","df_var12_20","df_var22_20","df_var13_20","df_var23_20","df_var14_20","df_var24_20"]
    names_plot02 = ["df_var0_50","df_var11_50","df_var21_50","df_var12_50","df_var22_50","df_var13_50","df_var23_50","df_var14_50","df_var24_50"]
    names_plot03 = ["df_var0_80","df_var11_80","df_var21_80","df_var12_80","df_var22_80","df_var13_80","df_var23_80","df_var14_80","df_var24_80"]
    names_plot04 = ["df_var0_96","df_var11_96","df_var21_96","df_var12_96","df_var22_96","df_var13_96","df_var23_96","df_var14_96","df_var24_96"]
    names_plot05 = ["df_var0_98","df_var11_98","df_var21_98","df_var12_98","df_var22_98","df_var13_98","df_var23_98","df_var14_98","df_var24_98"]
    color_setting = ["","","--","","--","","--","","--"]
    label_setting = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I"]
    plotcolor_setting = [plotcolors[0],plotcolors[1],plotcolors[1],
                     plotcolors[2],plotcolors[2],plotcolors[3],
                     plotcolors[3],plotcolors[4],plotcolors[4]]
    
    plot_names=zip(names_plot01,names_plot02,names_plot03,names_plot04,names_plot05,color_setting,label_setting,plotcolor_setting)

    for i in plot_names:
        
    axs[0].plot(([i][0][Name]),[i][5],color = [i][6],label = [i][7])
    
    
    axs[1].plot([i][1][Name],[i][5],color = [i][6],label = [i][7])
    
    
    axs[2].plot([i][2][Name],[i][5],color = [i][6],label = [i][7])
    
    
    axs[3].plot([i][3][Name],[i][5],color = [i][6],label = [i][7])
    
    
    axs[4].plot([i][4][Name],[i][5],color = [i][6],label = [i][7])
        

    fig.savefig(str(fileoutput)+ '.jpg',bbox_inches='tight',quality=95,dpi=300)
```

if I do so, i receive a TypeError:

```
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

which I dont really understand! The argument "Name" corresponds to a dataframe column.

Any hints on my wrong usage of zip() inside that plotting function are highly appreciated!

Comment: This is a lot of code to stare at where we don't have your data. Could you reproduce your issue with a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? As far as how to use `zip`, I personally use it to couple values I want to plot in a loop, like if `a` and `b` are lists of lists of values, I plot them with `for adx, bdx in zip(a, b): ; plt.plot(adx,bdx)`

Answer (score 0):

At the core of your current issue is the expression `[i][0][Name]`. This is making a new one-element list containing `i`, then indexing to get `i` back again (zero is the only acceptable index, most of the other similar expressions would fail if you got to them) and then indexing into `i` with `Name`. That's where you're getting an exception, since `i` is a tuple made by `zip` and you're tying to index it with a string. You probably don't want the brackets around `[i]`, you just want `i` itself (or even to be unpacking the tuple currently named `i` so you can give separate names to the inner values).

While that's the narrow issue that you're facing immediately, there are a few wider issues with your code and your efforts to using `zip` to improve it, so rather than directly addressing the current issue, I'm going to discuss them first, and then try solving everything together.

One wider issue is that a string like `"df_var0_20"` is not going to be directly related to the variable name `df_var0_20`, which seems to be the fundamental premise of your new code. I'm not exactly sure why you're using strings at all, you can pack the dataframes into lists just as easily as you can strings. It *is* a bit of a code smell that you have a whole lot of variable names that are only differentiated by numbers. Probably those should have been stored in lists already (though since they're not sequential numbers, maybe dictionaries would be even better).

Another issue is that your big repetitive block of code seems to have at least two different dimensions to it, which probably means you need nested loops if you're going to simplify it down (zip only helps you match up several values along one dimension at a time). One dimension of your data controls the index into `axs` and the `20`/`50`/`80`/`96`/`98` suffix on the dataframe names. The other dimension controls the `var0`/`var11`/`var21`/`var12`/... infix of the dataframe variable names, and the `label` and `color` values (and I guess the `"--"` bits, whatever they are).

So I'd suggest some nested loops that look something like this:

```
for index, suffix in enumerate(suffixes):
    for infix, label, color, dash in zip(infixes, colors, labels, dashes):
        axs[index].plot(dataframe_lookup[infix, suffix], dash,
                        color=color, label=label, linewidth=3)
```

You'll need to figure out what `dataframe_lookup` should be (I'm accessing it like a dictionary with tuple keys, but some other structure might make more sense for your data). If you don't want to use dictionaries, you could perhaps make a list of lists of dataframes grouped by suffix, and then directly get at the dataframes with the loop code (you'd replace `suffixes` with the list of lists, and `suffix` would be an inner list that you'd pass to the `zip` call in place of `infixes`).